# Access VBA - Separate identical forms with different record sources?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Instead of creating 3 separate identical forms with different record/control sources how can I create a combobox that uses the same form but changes the record source(a table) depending on selection in combobox?

So far I tried this on click event(se below) but it just opens a form with #Name? inserted in textfields.

```
Private Sub cmbMain_Click()
' combobox main form

 Select Case cmbMain

    Case "A"

   DoCmd.OpenForm "FormX", , , OpenArgs:=Me.RecordSource = "tblA"


    Case "B"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormX", , , OpenArgs:=Me.RecordSource = "tblB"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you use the `OpenArgs` argument. `OpenArgs` is just for passing a string to a form.

Instead, you can use the `Forms` collection to set the recordsource:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormX"
Forms!FormX.Recordsource = "tblA"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tried that but after selecting FormX in the combox it just shuts down the form without any error message...

Comment: That's not reproducible with the currently shared code. Why is FormX in that combo box anyway, in your sample it's just A and B?

Comment: Cross posted with answers here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=300516